# Pipe program stdout to a crossbar.io router

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, crossbar, wamp-protocol

How can I send the `stdout` of a compilation process to a crossbar.io-Router?

I am working on a travis-like continuous-integration-system for compiling Github-hosted LaTeX documents/projects. The server receives a POST from Github and starts the compilation process. The compiler's output should then be displayed real-time in a virtual console on a website.

Is this possible with `crossbar.io` and `autobahn|Python` running on Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, possible. I estimate roughly 50 lines Python code + JS in browser (dump to JS console: 20 lines).

Here is what you need to do when using [AutobahnPython](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython) plus Python 2 and [Twisted](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython):

1. Write a Twisted Web resource that receives the HTTP/POST
2. Upon receiving the POST, start a child process (your compiler thing) using Twisted's [process support](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html)
3. Upon receiving stuff from `stdout` from the child process, publish WAMP events to Crossbar.io via ..
4. .. a WAMP app component that you previously created and connected to Crossbar.io